# My Ajax Class Does Not Work

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've made a JavaScript class to make Ajax requests easier.

My class :

```
var ajax =
{
    method:"GET",
    action:"",
    data : "",
    result: "",

    setResult : function(re){this.result = re;},
    setMethod : function(method){this.method = method.toUpperCase();},
    setAction : function(page){this.action = page;},
    addData : function(name,value){data_for_setting_data = name+"="+value+"&";this.data += data_for_setting_data;},

    send : function()
    {
        var XMLHttpRequestObject = false;
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
            XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
        else if(window.ActiveXObject)
            XMLHttpRequestObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        else
        {
            try
            {
                XMLHttpRequestObject = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if(XMLHttpRequestObject)
        {
            var resulter;
            datalength = this.data.length;
            datasender = this.data.substr(0,datalength-1);
            switch(this.method)
            {
                case "GET" :
                    XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET",this.action+"?"+datasender,true);
                    XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function()
                    {
                        if(XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4)
                        {
                            this.result = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
                        }
                    }
                    XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null);
                ;
                break;
                case "POST" :
                    XMLHttpRequestObject.open("POST",this.action,true);
                    XMLHttpRequestObject.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    XMLHttpRequestObject.send(datasender);
                    XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function()
                    {
                        if(XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4)
                        {
                            this.result = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
                        }
                    }                   
                ;break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I send a data like this :

```
ajax.setAction("a.php");
ajax.setMethod("get");
ajax.addData("myname","mohsen");
ajax.send();
alert(ajax.result);
```

the result will be nothing.

But for example, on line 44, if I use

```
alert(XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText)
```

instead of

```
this.result = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
```

it will work correctly.

What should I do to solve this problem ?

And one more question: Does it reduce loading speed?

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot use jQuery's [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)?

Comment: Yes . Because Ajax's Directory Is Too Heavy For Client Part And It's Not A Goof Idea To Use That Just For Ajax !And Of Course I Have Other Reasons that is for my site ...

Comment: You are trying to access `ajax.result` **before** it was set. Ajax is **asychronous**. That's why you have to assign a callback to  `XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange`. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/218196 to learn the differences between synchronous code and asynchronous code and to handle the response of Ajax calls. You have to work with *callbacks*.

Comment: My English Is Not Good you Know :((

Comment: Still Don't know what to do.

Comment: Should you be checking against `if(XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState==4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status==200)` ?

Comment: I did that still have that problem it returs nothing ...

Comment: Please Help I Am Getting Crazy :((

Comment: AJAX is ASYNCHRONOUS, as someone said before. It means it will not wait until data is loaded, control is passed. When data is loaded, the "onreadystatechange" event will fire and there is where you need to define an "event handler" function.

Comment: You shouldn't have this behaviour wrapped in a singleton. Consider using constructors and prototypes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `this.result`, `this` does not refer to your `ajax` variable. To fix this, change to:

```
ajax.result = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
```

Or declare a variable to hold the current context object:

```
send : function()
    {
       var self = this;
```

And use it like this:

```
self.result = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
```

One more problem with your code. Because ajax is asyn, when you call `alert(ajax.result);`. The response from the server may not arrive yet. To fix the asyn problem, you could either use syn request by setting the final parameter to `false` (although this approach is not recommended as it blocks the browser, the app will appear hung if the request takes long time to complete)

```
XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET",this.action+"?"+datasender,false);
```

Or pass in a callback function. When the ajax response has arrived, call it:

```
 send : function(callback){
  ....your code
      if(XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4)
      {
            if (typeof callback === "function"){ 
                callback(XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText);
            }
      }
 }
```

Use it like this:

```
ajax.send(function(result){
      alert(result);
});
```

Comment: Actually, `this` refers `XMLHttpRequestObject`. And still, the OP is trying to access the value before it is set.

Comment: The best way is call back as you said and it was really nice :X

Comment: self is not a good choice. You're overshadowing a global variable.